# PHP 5.5.9 namespace issue

Tags: php, namespaces

I am running apache2 on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS with 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.

I was uploading a working code to the server but got "NetworkError: 500 Internal Server Error"

So I started tracking down the problem. I traced it back and found out it seems to be a problem with namespace declaration. In trying to figure it out (simplify things) I created a new file that duplicates the error.

```
<?php
    namespace MyProject ;

    echo '"', __NAMESPACE__, '"'; // outputs "MyProject"
?>
```

When put through a browser it generates the above error.

If I comment out the 2nd line, it runs without error and produces the expected output

```
""
```

Any ideas what is happening?

Comment: What does your **error log** say? "500" is just Apache's reaction to PHP failing, PHP itself will have a more detailed error in its logs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is just a semilicon `;` missing on the second line:

```
<?php
   namespace MyProject ;

   echo '"', __NAMESPACE__, '"'; // outputs "MyProject"
?>
```

You should also get rid of the spaces and blank lines before your `<?php` opening tag.

Comment: Sorry the problem exists with the ";". It was missing due to a typo...  I have edited the original question.

Comment: @farley: Have you got anything else on this page? Copy and paste page code [here](http://pastebin.com)

Comment: @Notulyssues - In order to track this down and make sure there was nothing else I have nothing else on the page. The code above now exactly matches the code I am running through my browser. Comment out the namespace line and I get output. Leave it uncommented and I get the 500 Error. Seems PHP is not parsing the 'namespace' declaration.

Comment: @Notulyssues - [paste](http://pastebin.com/gA6MpxB1) just picked up on the pastbin

Comment: @farley : I don't know, it works fine on my machine. I can't suggest anything more than just check any spaces before `<?php` tag .One more thing : Are there any errors in your php log?

Comment: I think I figured it out. The error log did say that the namespace has to be on the very first line. But I noticed that I had a blank line before the <?php line. I got rid of that and it works now. Thanks for your help that led me to this.

Comment: @farley : Glad to help you!Mark as answered, please.