# PHP namespace declaration statement has to be the very first

Tags: php

I know that there are many questions like this on SO, but in my case it looks a bit different. So, I have such a file:

```
<?php
namespace IdentityAccess\Model\User;
class User {
    public function __construct () {} 
}
$user = new User();
?>
```

And I must confess, that there is no space after `<?php`

```
<?php//Here we have absolutelly no space
namespace IdentityAccess\Model\User;
```

But still, I get this error message in browser:

> Fatal error: Namespace declaration statement has to be the very first statement in the script

However, if I do it like so:

```
<?phpnamespace IdentityAccess\Model\User;
class User {
    public function __construct () {} 
}
$user = new User();
?>
```

it raises no error, but it looks just terrible. I mean this ugly `<?phpnamespace`. But I guess, that I do something wrong and hope somebody can advise.

Comment: `<?phpnamespace` should not even **work** at all. there **has** to be a space inbetween. also: could not reproduce on PHP 5.6.29. is there maybe anything before the `<?php`? because that's not allowed, either. even a single whitespace character will break it.

Comment: No, there are absolutely no spaces, even before `<?php`

Comment: Hm. Probably, the whole problem is in old PHP version?

Comment: always a possibility. what version are you using?

Comment: are you including this file any where if yes how ?

Comment: I've just checked it. It is `5.5.0RC3`

Comment: @Rishi. No. I have not tried to include it yet

Comment: possibly related? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23275862/php-5-5-9-namespace-issue anyway, updating from php 5.5.0*RC3* should be a good idea in general.

Comment: And don't you know in what version namespaces appeared (as well as interfaces, since I also need to use them)?